# jnlp.BasicService.showDocument url permission denied with all-permissions and signed jar

Tags: java, jar, permissions, jnlp, signed

I have an applet running in jnlp. My single jar file is signed. I accept the permissions prompt each time the JNLP client is launched. I can obtain the BasicService but it still throws a url permission denied exception when I try to follow a URI:

```
file:///D:\temp\test.txt
```

The file is present on all the Windows client machines I've tried and there are no security issues with opening it.

The issue happens when using a 32 or 64-bit JRE on the client. The server is 32-bit but I would think this irrelevant. The only clue (or red-herring perhaps) is that I get no security exception when the client and server are on the same host. If I use a remote client then I get the exception.

Whilst I needed to include the jnlp.jar file to compile the code, I assume it is not needed on the client if run using Java WebStart.

What else might you need to know? What else should I try?

Later that day...

Now this may or may not be a bug, it may be something wrong with the parameters in my jnlp file but I suspect that I'm using the wrong approach. Just to reitterate I'm trying to open a `file://` url.

***Here is what I am now doing:***

I assumed that the Desktop facilities were only available in a Desktop Application - not an applet. I was wrong (and the documentation is scant - even on this hallowed site the only reference tells me to use JNLP Services for an Applet and Desktop for an Application) - Wrong (thankfully)

So you can use Desktop (having first checked that `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` of course) in an applet - as long as you are running through WebStart not embedded as an applet.

I would propose the following approach to anyone.

1. See if Desktop is supported and use that.

   `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);`
2. If not then see if you can get the Basic JNLP Service.

   `BasicService bs = (BasicService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService");`

   and if that is available the use it with `boolean openedOK = bs.showDocument(url);`
3. Finally resort to the applet API.

   `AppletContext context = applet.getAppletContext();`

   `context.showDocument(url, targetFrame);`

Comment: *"`file://` url"*  I am pretty sure I have seen a closed bug that decided that `BasicService.showDocument(URI)` & possibly also the applet method were 'not intended' to work for file based URIs.  Wish I could find it now..  In any case, why not access the file according to the code base or document base?